# disable jqWidgets jqxwindow autoClose feature

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jqWidgets UI Framework. The problem is in using jqxWindow. It is autoclosed after some seconds. There is no function to disable autoclose in its documentation [here](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxwindow/jquery-window-api.htm)

I have also checked its jqxwindow.js file there is no clue find in it.

Please help if there is a method of disabling it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you want you can use jquery.dialog() and the dialogExtend it has the same functionality as jqxWindow and please can u post your code so we can help u ?

Comment: You can see its documentation. I am using the same.